# React JS Download Document from Server and Upload it on another Server

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm using React JS to DownloadDocument through Rest API. API Returning to me

Rest API in Dot Net Core -

```
Stream stream = DownloadDocument(accessToken);
string mimeType = "application/pdf";
return File(stream, mimeType, "DC_Signed.pdf");
```

Now in React JS, we have to Read/Download Documents and Upload them on Third Party API i.e SharePoint

Any suggestions or ways to do that?